# jQuery selecting row from form which has a certain class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently having trouble getting my selector right.
What I'm trying to do is get a row which has a certain class name and is inside a form which has another class name. I have 2 forms in my html page, both of them have a row with the same class name. Right now, jQuery chooses the first one and then the second one does nothing.
Basically, I'm adding a row of input to a table in a form, and I want to be able to add that row in both of my forms respectively.

Here is my code for adding a row:

```
$('input.add').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $class = $(this).closest('form').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    var $clone = $('tr.addRow:last').clone();

    if($clone.children().hasClass('auto_increment'))
    {
        var $nbre = $clone.children().first().text();
        $clone.children().first().text(++$nbre);
    }               
    $clone.wrap('<div>');
    var newRow = $clone.parent().html();

    $('tr.addRow:last').after(newRow);              
});
```

Yes it is after jQuery has loaded.
As you can see, I'm getting the class name of the form, but I just can't get the selector in the last line right.
Thank you, Ben.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="Items next_page_form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Items</legend>
                <table class="table_spacing" id="removableData">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ITEM</td>
                        <td>QT&Eacute</td>
                        <td>DESCRIPTION</td>                            
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="addRow">
                        <td class="auto_increment">1</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity"></td>
                        <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td>                           
                        <td><input type="button" class="removeData" style="margin-left:5px; background-image:url(./images/delete.jpg); width:30px; height:30px; background-size:100%"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><input type="button" class="add" value="Ajouter" style="margin-right:15px; margin-left:10px;"><input type="button" class="remove" value="Enlever"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 
        <form class="envoi next_page_form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Envoi</legend>
                <table class="table_spacing">
                    <tr>
                        <td>NO</td>
                        <td>DESTINATAIRE</td>
                        <td>CONTACT</td>
                        <td>COMMENTAIRE</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="addRow">
                        <td class="auto_increment">1</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="recipient">
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="contact">
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><textarea name="comments"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4"><input type="button" class="add" value="Ajouter" style="margin-right:15px; margin-left:10px;"><input type="button" class="remove" value="Enlever"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not have a `<tr>` with the class of `addRow` in the second form.  Second, your selector needs to only select the `<tr>` with the class of `addRow` **in the current form**.  So, using jQuery traversal, you would write:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('tr.addRow:last')
```

Whenever you need the last addRow in the current form.

Here is the complete, refactored code:

```
$('input.add').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var $class = form.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    var $clone = form.find('tr.addRow:last').clone();
    if($clone.children().hasClass('auto_increment'))
    {
        var $nbre = $clone.children().first().text();
        $clone.children().first().text(++$nbre);
    }               
    $clone.wrap('<div>');
    var newRow = $clone.parent().html();
    form.find('tr.addRow:last').after(newRow);              
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kZZeb/6/)**

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery traversal? And thanks for your answer but they still get mixed up. By the way I updated the html file to add that second addRow class

Comment: @ben_thibs jQuery traversal is the use of jQuery methods (such as .closest()) to tranverse, or move along, the DOM (which is basically your HTML element tree).  Did you see my demo?  As far as I tested, they did not get mixed up.  Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I have done a remove input that does the same thing and the remove works for both forms... I have an alert method to show me the form html and it shows me the good one but maybe I need to stock it in a variable? Am doing this now : $(this).closest('form').find('tr.addRow:last').after(newRow);

Comment: @ben_thibs So it removes the row from both forms?  You did not include that remove code with the original code, so I did not know there was a problem with it.  If you want to update your original question, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: No the remove button works the right way. If I push it in the second form, it removes a row from the second form only, that's the way I want it. But the add button adds rows at the good spot, but not of the good type in the first form case...

Comment: In that first form, on the add button click, I get a row from the second form. On that second form, I get a row from the second form.

Comment: @ben_thibs I don't see that in my fiddle.  There must be some other code in your project that is doing that.

Comment: My problem was with the find... I had to find the last addRow within the form... I didn't see that form.find in the clone variable. My bad and thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply target the table parent and then look for the last of the addRow class

http://jsfiddle.net/kZZeb/5/

```
$('input.add').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    var $class = table.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    var $clone = table.find('tr.addRow:last').clone();
    var cloneChildren = $clone.children();

    if(cloneChildren.hasClass('auto_increment'))
    {
        var $nbre = cloneChildren.first().text();
        cloneChildren.first().text(++$nbre);
    }

    $clone.wrap('<div>');
    var newRow = $clone.parent().html();
    table.find('tr.addRow:last').after(newRow);              
});
```